# Copy C# datatable into mysql database table

Tags: c#, mysql-connector, multiple-insert

I have created one DataTable in C# dynamically. I want to insert this whole DataTable in MySql database table.

I am using MySql hence SqlBulkCopy is not an option for me.
I have tried MySqlBulkLoader but it seems it only insert data from file.

I can do it via iterating through every datarow of datatable and insert it to database.

Is there any another way I can achieve multiple inserts into database?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What is the number of rows you are looing at ?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the number of rows are not much you can simply create an insert statement
INSERT INTO table VALUES (1,2,3), (4,5,6), (7,8,9);

Another article at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19727/ADO-NET-Generic-Copy-Table-Data-Function may help.

Though, if the number of rows are high, you can probably create a temporary text file and then use BulkLoader !